# CodeIgniter 3 выбор языка валидации

Tags: php, codeigniter

есть скрипт проверяющий на валидацию, он рабочий, но нужно изменить язык, в папке *system/language* присутствует только английский язык

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
    $config = array(
        array(
            'field'   => 'email',
            'label'   => 'введите емейл',
            'rules'   => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field'   => 'fio',
            'label'   => 'введите ФИО/НИК',
            'rules'   => 'required'
        ),
        array(
            'field'   => 'text',
            'label'   => 'введите комментарий',
            'rules'   => 'required'
        )
    );

    $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
```

данный скрипт выдает: *The введите емейл field is required.*

Comment: так загрузите языки, их там есть

Comment: @splash58 в гугле и других поисковых система только такие примеры, нигде не нашел из отдельно загруженным пакетом языков

Comment: Там же где загрузить, рядом Translations. Подставляете. У меня все заработало

Comment: Только вместо "введите емейл" просто "емейл"

Comment: @splash58 это самому надо вручную переводить, может есть более лояльный способ?